# no visible @interface for UIImageView declares the selector sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView and sd_setIndicatorStyle is not detected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, sdwebimage

It is very strange that `sd_setImageWithURL` is working but got an error in `sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView:YES` and `sd_setIndicatorStyle`.

Below what I have done.

```
[cell.cellImgView sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView:YES];
[cell.cellImgView sd_setIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

[cell.cellImgView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://img.youtube.com/vi/%@/hqdefault.jpg",[[[galleryDic objectForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"Video_id"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"youtube-video"] ];
```

Please see the image below:
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out now, Well I have to import `#import "UIView+WebCache.h"` too along with others then i have used following:

```
[cell.cellImgView sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView:YES];
[cell.cellImgView sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
```

Also, I removed the SDWebImage folder, what i used to integrate manually, then I have installed it through `POD' again, and now it is working as i wanted.

Answer (score 8):

For anybody who has this issue in 2019

`sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView` has been removed in SDWebImage v5

Use this instead

```
imageView1.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.gray
//or
imageView2.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageProgressIndicator.`default`
//or
imageView2.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.medium //large, small, gray ...
```

Answer (score 6):

I migrate to version 4.0.

and

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIView+WebCache.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such method like `sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView` and `sd_setIndicatorStyle` in `SDWebImage`>`UIImageView+WebCache.h` that's why it shows no visible @interface for `UIImageView` declares the selector `sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView` and `sd_setIndicatorStyle` is not detected

Instead of that use following.

```
 [cell.cellImgView setShowActivityIndicatorView:YES]; 
 [cell.cellImgView setIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
```

Here are these methods in `UIImageView+WebCache.h`

```
/**
 *  Show activity UIActivityIndicatorView
 */
- (void)setShowActivityIndicatorView:(BOOL)show;

/**
 *  set desired UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle
 *
 *  @param style The style of the UIActivityIndicatorView
 */
- (void)setIndicatorStyle:(UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle)style;
```

Comment: what is the difference from my code ?? I copied and pasted your code then realized it is same, and throwing the same error.

Comment: `[cell.cellImgView sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView:YES]; 
[cell.cellImgView sd_setIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];`  And and answer `[cell.cellImgView setShowActivityIndicatorView:YES]; 
 [cell.cellImgView setIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];` both are same ?

Comment: No, My mistake, did that and now it can mapped to `UIImageView+WebCache.h` class, if I press cmd and on method name, but error is not going, i cleaned several times but during build errors come again.

Comment: This methods are in `#import "UIView+WebCache.h"` by importing such file in my desired class and installing the sdwebimage by pods, its started working. Thanks anyway, I appreciate your time for me.

Answer (score 1):

Import following file

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"

#import "UIImageView+UIActivityIndicatorForSDWebImage.h"
```

Comment: or import another UIIMageVIew category file which are consists this method.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: try to import UIImageView+UIActivityIndicatorForSDWebImage.h file ....if exist in your project

Comment: is this file exist in your project : "UIImageView+WebCache.h" ?

Comment: No there is no such file, but i downloaded it from this link https://github.com/JJSaccolo/UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage and integrated, then did `#import "UIImageView+UIActivityIndicatorForSDWebImage.h"` though it is not working. And yes `UIImageView+WebCache.h` this file is available ..

Comment: then it will working this file because this method declared on this class.

Comment: then import this file UIImageView+UIActivityIndicatorForSDWebImage.h

Comment: Look these all files are there https://ibb.co/eRVK8F and I'm using it in pods, and from this link  github.com/rs/SDWebImage , i got the idea to attach such indicator.

Comment: `#import <UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage/UIImageView+UIActivityIndicatorForSDWebImage.h>` This throwing error , despite that, `#import "UIImageView+UIActivityIndicatorForSDWebImage.h"` it is not throwing error.

Comment: yes it is but i mentioned because user can understand this sp

Comment: I uninstall it from pod and manually dragged and dropped it into the project, everything seems is okay but same result for that `sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView` and `sd_setIndicatorStyle` :/

Comment: try to clean project .

Comment: @KKRocks `sd_setImageWithURL` is accessed that means there is nothing wrong with importing the `SDWebImage`

Comment: I figured it out @KKRocks, By importing `#import "UIView+WebCache.h"` and installing `SDWebImage` in pods, it started working. Gone those errors. Thanks for your time, I appreciate you for helping me in so many ways. And please upvote my answer it is working now.

Comment: @KKRocks I did.. and happy coding :)